# Web Data Connector executes the Route multiple times

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am using WDC, which has 3 tables. All three tables extracts data from the same route. Now, when I run the WDC, backend route is executed 12 times! For the first 9 executions, I am not allowed to click anywhere. If I do so, Tableau stops responding. After 9 executions, I see data in the Tableau desktop, and then backend route is executed 3 more times while creating extract. During these 3 executions, I am allowed to click anywhere!

Could you please explain why it executes the route multiple times?

Thank you in advance.

I tried to understand why it is happening.

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question above?